# Php calendar, to use ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple code for a php calendar and I would like to make it use ajax when I go to next or previous month.
I am not very familiar with ajax nor jquery.
How can i achieve it? Code:

```
<?php

$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

if (!isset($_GET["m"])) $_GET["m"] = date("n"); 
if (!isset($_GET["y"])) $_GET["y"] = date("Y");

$currentMonth = $_GET["m"];
$currentYear = $_GET["y"];

$p_year = $currentYear;
$n_year = $currentYear;
$p_month = $currentMonth-1;
$n_month = $currentMonth+1;

if ($p_month == 0 ) {
    $p_month = 12;
    $p_year = $currentYear - 1;
}

if ($n_month == 13 ) {
    $n_month = 1;
    $n_year = $currentYear + 1;
}
$days=array('1'=>"S",'2'=>"M",'3'=>"T",'4'=>"W",'5'=>"T",'6'=>"F",'7'=>"S");

?>

<table width="800">
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left">  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?m=".$p_month . "&y=" . $p_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Prev</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?m=".$n_month . "&y=" . $n_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%"  border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF"><B><?php echo  $monthNames[$currentMonth-1].' '.$currentYear; ?></B></td>
</tr>
<tr >
<?php for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){ ?>

<td align="center" height='100' bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF"><B><?php echo $days[$i]; ?></B></td>

<?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$currentMonth,1,$currentYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td ></td>";
    else echo "<td align='center'    height='80' valign='middle' bgcolor='#AED5E4' height='20px'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have added the entire code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider you have two files 1 **calendar.php** which contains your main calendar code and another file **calendar2.php** that is also contains ajax calendar code.  Try this codes.

Below code is for **calendar.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#next_d").click(function(event){
        var next1=$("#year_n").val();
        var nex2=$("#month_n").val();
          $.get( 
             "calendar2.php",
             {y: next1,m: nex2 },
             function(data) {
                $('#ajax_div').html(data);
             }

          );
      });

       $("#prev_d").click(function(event){
        var next1=$("#year_p").val();
        var nex2=$("#month_p").val();
          $.get( 
             "calendar2.php",
             {y: next1,m: nex2 },
             function(data) {
                $('#ajax_div').html(data);
             }

          );
      });
   });
</script>
<?php

$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

if (!isset($_GET["m"])) $_GET["m"] = date("n"); 
if (!isset($_GET["y"])) $_GET["y"] = date("Y");

$currentMonth = $_GET["m"];
$currentYear = $_GET["y"];

$p_year = $currentYear;
$n_year = $currentYear;
$p_month = $currentMonth-1;
$n_month = $currentMonth+1;

if ($p_month == 0 ) {
    $p_month = 12;
    $p_year = $currentYear - 1;
}

if ($n_month == 13 ) {
    $n_month = 1;
    $n_year = $currentYear + 1;
}
$days=array('1'=>"S",'2'=>"M",'3'=>"T",'4'=>"W",'5'=>"T",'6'=>"F",'7'=>"S");

?>
</head>
<body>
<button id="prev_d">Prev</button> <button id="next_d">Next</button>
<div id="ajax_div">
<input type='hidden' name='year' id="year_n" value="<?php echo $n_year; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='month' id="month_n" value="<?php echo $n_month; ?>">

<input type='hidden' name='year' id="year_p" value="<?php echo $p_year; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='month' id="month_p" value="<?php echo $p_month; ?>">

<table width="800">

<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>

</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%"  border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF"><B><?php echo  $monthNames[$currentMonth-1].' '.$currentYear; ?></B></td>
</tr>
<tr >
<?php for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){ ?>

<td align="center" height='100' bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF"><B><?php echo $days[$i]; ?></B></td>

<?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$currentMonth,1,$currentYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td ></td>";
    else echo "<td align='center'    height='80' valign='middle' bgcolor='#AED5E4' height='20px'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<body>
</html>
```

And below code is for **calendar2.php**

```
<html>
<head>

<?php

$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

if (!isset($_GET["m"])) $_GET["m"] = date("n"); 
if (!isset($_GET["y"])) $_GET["y"] = date("Y");

$currentMonth = $_GET["m"];
$currentYear = $_GET["y"];

$p_year = $currentYear;
$n_year = $currentYear;
$p_month = $currentMonth-1;
$n_month = $currentMonth+1;

if ($p_month == 0 ) {
    $p_month = 12;
    $p_year = $currentYear - 1;
}

if ($n_month == 13 ) {
    $n_month = 1;
    $n_year = $currentYear + 1;
}
$days=array('1'=>"S",'2'=>"M",'3'=>"T",'4'=>"W",'5'=>"T",'6'=>"F",'7'=>"S");

?>
</head>
<body>

<div id="ajax_div">
<input type='hidden' name='year' id="year_n" value="<?php echo $n_year; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='month' id="month_n" value="<?php echo $n_month; ?>">

<input type='hidden' name='year' id="year_p" value="<?php echo $p_year; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='month' id="month_p" value="<?php echo $p_month; ?>">

<table width="800">

<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left"> </td>
<td width="50%" align="right"></td>

</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%"  border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF"><B><?php echo  $monthNames[$currentMonth-1].' '.$currentYear; ?></B></td>
</tr>
<tr >
<?php for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){ ?>

<td align="center" height='100' bgcolor="#7DC3E3" style="color:#FFFFFF"><B><?php echo $days[$i]; ?></B></td>

<?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$currentMonth,1,$currentYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td ></td>";
    else echo "<td align='center'    height='80' valign='middle' bgcolor='#AED5E4' height='20px'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any guess how could i change the order of days?  as putting sunday at the end of the week?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php change date(n) for Monday as first and Sunday as last.

Answer (score 1):

Add javascript events listening on month and year changes to tear down and rebuild the table with the new calendar view, for bonus points rewrite the apparent URL so when bookmarked the correct view is redrawn when the URL is revisted later.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class in your prev/next links , for example  `<a class="newcalendar" href="<?php echo 'calendar.php?m='.$p_month . '&y='.$p_year.'">'`

Then attach an event "onclick" which will make a `$.ajax`, `$.get`, or `$.load` (check the jquery documentation to know what's best for you) to execute the request and then place the output in the appropriate field (so you will need to add `id="calendar"` on the container.

Here a small example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".newcalendar", function(e){
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  $("#calendar").load(url);
});
```